# Single Sign Out user from Sitecore after session expiration

Tags: identity-server, azure-ad

We are using *Sitecore 10.3 XM* and have *Azure AD* SSO for logging into Sitecore CMS. We have specified the Session timeout value as 20 mins, which means after 20 mins of inactivity on the CMS, the user will be logged out of Sitecore, which is working as expected.

But it is not logging out the user from an external identity (Microsoft SSO in our case). Can anyone please guide how can we achieve Single Sign out on session expiration?

Things we have already tried:

- Checked `<triggerExternalSignOut>` setting in `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` , this is set to **true**
- On the identity server, defined `<PostLogoutRedirectUri3>https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/logout</PostLogoutRedirectUri3>` at the path `sitecore/Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer/Config/identityServer.xml`

Comment: Not sure what is the reasoning behind why you are trying to log the user out of Azure AD when they log out of Sitecore CMS.

Comment: If users are not signed out of external identity, then signing in to Sitecore can happen without even entering the credentials. We want Single Sign Out to implement.